# Cmake/Cpack Debian packaging - producing correct package name

Tags: debian, cpack

I'm attempting to build a properly named Debian package using Cpack.  I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME "something")
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "amd64")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE "amd64")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR "9")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH "0")
set(CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION "${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MAJOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_MINOR}.${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION_PATCH}")
```

but I get file named:

```
 something-0.9.0-Linux.deb
```

Instead of:

```
something-0.9.0_amd64.deb
```

I've looked at the various documentation pages but haven't found the answer.

Answer (score 6):

Cpack does not have `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME`, may be this should be reported as bug, not all GNU/Linux-BSD systems have same package naming convention.

For now, You can set [`CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/module/CPack.html?highlight=cpack#variable:CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME) which is set by default to:

```
${CPACK_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_SYSTEM_NAME}.
```

Follow the link to read the full documentation page.

> **[`CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/module/CPackDeb.html)**
>
> The Debian package architecture
>
> ```
> Mandatory : YES
> Default : Output of `dpkg --print-architecture` (or 'i386' if dpkg is not found)
> ```

You may set the file name as:

`set(CPACK_PACKAGE_FILE_NAME "${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_NAME}-${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_VERSION}-${CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE}.")`

By the way, no need to override defaults if they are good.

- `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_ARCHITECTURE` defaults to `dpkg --print-architecture`
- `CPACK_DEBIAN_PACKAGE_VERSION` defaults to `CPACK_PACKAGE_VERSION` which by itself is built from `major.minor.patch`.

Comment: I'm looking for Cpack to figure out that it is an amd64 package and name it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

**Update for cmake >=3.6**: Use

```
set(CPACK_DEBIAN_FILE_NAME DEB-DEFAULT)
```

Please note that explicitly setting the default is necessary here.
Quoting the  [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/module/CPackDeb.html):

> Preferred setting of this variable is DEB-DEFAULT but for backward compatibility with CPackDeb in CMake prior to version 3.6 this feature is disabled by default.